# Unreachable Code: 3 cannot be resolved to a type errors & 3 undefined for the type errors

Tags: java, android, syntax-error, android-adapter, curly-brackets

My main issue is I'm getting an error stating: `ImagePagerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type`  on line 80:

Line 80 is `ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();`

and I'm also getting a warning stating:  `The type Home.ThumbnailLoadedListener.ImagePagerAdapter is never used locally`

I'm pretty sure my ImagePagerAdapter can't be reached due to a misplaced closing bracket - I've tried adjusting a few of them but I'm just having a bit of trouble nailing down which one is causing the issue (or if perhaps it might be something else)

I am also getting several other errors related to a large block of the code (basically the 2nd half) being undefined/unreached but I'm 99% sure this is all interrealted to a syntax issue or a misplaced bracket.

### ALL ERRORS:

```
ImagePagerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type line 80
ImagePagerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type line 80 
ThumbnailListener cannot be resolved to a type line 225 
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) is undefined for the type Object  line 246 
The method onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) is undefined for the type Object line 238  
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) is undefined for the type Object  line 257
```

P.S.

I apologize for the extensive amount of code - I'm just not sure it would be possible to resolve if I only showed part of it.

### SOURCE:

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";
    public static final String VIDEO3_ID = "83ZgtqTw-mI";
    public static final String VIDEO4_ID = "n5wMza29JwI";
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView3;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView4;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader3;
    private boolean nextThumbnailLoaded;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
                );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

        fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                        .getBackground()
                        .getConstantState()
                        .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
                // set the background
                fav_up_btn1
                .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                        : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO2_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview3);
        youTubeThumbnailView3.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO3_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview4);
        youTubeThumbnailView4.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO4_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {
        this.thumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailListener());

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {
            youTubeThumbnailLoader1.setVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
        }

        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns
            // true
            // then it has handled the app icon touch event
            if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.classical_up_btn,
                    R.drawable.country_up_btn, R.drawable.dance_up_btn,
                    R.drawable.hiphop_up_btn };

            public int getCount() {
                return mImages.length;
            }

            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == ((ImageView) object);
            }

            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                Context context = Home.this;
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.dimen.padding_medium);
                imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
                ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
                return imageView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                    Object object) {
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
            }

            private final class ThumbnailListener implements
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail,
                        String videoId) {
                    // nextThumbnailLoaded = true;
                    //
                    // if (activityResumed) {
                    // if (state.equals(State.LOADING_THUMBNAILS)) {
                    // flipNext();
                    // } else if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_FLIPPED_OUT)) {
                    // // load player with the video of the next thumbnail being
                    // flipped in
                    // state = State.VIDEO_LOADING;
                    // player.cueVideo(videoId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0,
                        ErrorReason arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }
        }

        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail,
                YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason reason) {
            loadNextThumbnail();
        }

        private void loadNextThumbnail() {
            nextThumbnailLoaded = false;
            if (thumbnailLoader.hasNext()) {
                thumbnailLoader.next();
            } else {
                thumbnailLoader.first();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `onCreateOptionsMenu` method to this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve 1/6 errors! Any suggestions regarding the other 5?

Comment: ? : ( I still really need help with this... any takers?

Comment: I don't know what are exactly in lines 80,225,246 and 238. Please Edit your question and specify them.